# Can I do low level network programming in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

An application level message is send over the network in a series of packets that are assembled in the receiving side and passed to the application level.
Is it possible in `Java` to do network programming in the level of these individual packets?
Or in `Java` we can only see the "application" level packet? I.e. the "big-packet" that is assembled by all these network packets?
I tried to research on google for this matter but the results where really confusing.
The confusion is due to the fact that some resources that are about UDP seem to indicate that the operation is on packets, while others say that Java can not work in raw sockets which implies that it works on a higher level of abstraction.I could not find an answer to exactly what I am looking for.
If yes, which package does this?

Comment: 1) Have tried google by keywords in question? 2) Why do you think none of those packages applicable for your scenario? Question lacking these details.

Comment: @Nambari:I have.I am confused since some resources that are about `UDP` seem to indicate that the operation is on packets, while others say that `Java` can not work in raw sockets which implies that it works on a higher level of abstraction.I could not find an answer to exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @Nambari:` Why do you think none of those packages applicable for your scenario?` Which packages? The `net` package seems to work in the message not the packets

Comment: Yes, net packages. I would suggest rephrase your question with these details. These details will let community know you have done some research and looking for specific information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible in Java to do network programming in the level of these individual packets?

Yes, but it's very unlikely you would want individual packets.

> Or in Java we can only see the "application" level packet?

Pure Java can only see TCP streams, and UDP datagram which have a one-to-one mapping with packets, but you have no access to the UDP header.

> I.e. the "big-packet" that is assembled by all these network packets?

You don't get packets at all big or small.  You read data and the data available is read (up to the size of your buffer)

> If yes, which package does this?

You can use JPcap to see individual packets, however, this is rarely useful unless you need  accurate time stamping of each packet or you need to trace dropped packets.

This uses winpcap (Windows) or libpcap (linux) via JNI.

In most of these cases where I have seen this used it was a lot of work for little gain.

> from my point of view an answer mentioning JNI means that Java does not support it (since you have to actually code in another language for what you need)

Sockets, Files, GUI components all use JNI in the end.  By this definition you can't do anything which uses a system call in Java, because the OS is not written in Java.

I don't think this is a useful definition of what you can do in Java.

> 1) Pure Java can only see TCP streams. What about UDP?

You don't have access to the packet's header with any protocol in Java without libPCap.

> I assume this point means no packet access

Not without any additional libraries.

> 2) In most of these cases where I have seen this used it was a lot of work ? Why.

Because it is very low level and lots of details you don't normally have to worry about are exposed to you. Note: you might not get a packet as they can be dropped while attempting to record them and you won't be able to ask for them again so you miss them.

> It is just a library right?

Correct.

> Doesn't it work?

Why do you say that?

> I am trying to see if what I need to do can be done in Java or should look into other languages.

IMHO, You won't find it any easier in another language.

> I read in the jpcap docs that it can not reshape traffic e.g. drop packets etc. Why can't it do that?

You can't force a network to drop a packet and you can't trick the kernel in to drop one either.  If you think about what a dropped packet is, the answer is fairly obvious.

Comment: 1) `Pure Java can only see TCP streams.` What about `UDP`? I assume this point means no packet access 2) `In most of these cases where I have seen this used it was a lot of work `? Why. It is just a library right? Doesn't it work?

Comment: `In most of these cases where I have seen this used it was a lot of work` I am not trying to find the limitation in Java. I am trying to see if what I need to do can be done in `Java` or should look into other languages. I prefer `Java` though

Comment: I read in the `jpcap` docs that it can not reshape traffic e.g. drop packets etc. Why can't it do that?

Comment: I have added tot he answer based on your comments.  Java 5.0 was released in 2004. https://github.com/jpcap/jpcap was last updated in 2011

Comment: But in their docs they state that:`it does not provide the appropriate support for applications like traffic shapers, QoS schedulers and personal firewalls.` But if I use it as a proxy won't it do exactly these? I.e. traffic shappers or blockers etc?

Comment: You are right in a way.  If you implement everything yourself and you have a machine attached to two networks you can pick up packets from one network and do whatever you like to the before passing them to a second network.  If you have a single network, you are seeing the packets AFTER the kernel sees them so you can't change what the kernel sees.

Comment: +1 thorough answer. I was about to mention winpcap. Have used in .net, great stuff. Good job.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:But even if in a single network, if my process acts like a proxy server won't I be able to block packets. Since the client will send to proxy and the proxy will drop them. Right?

Comment: @PeterLawrey:BTW is this a good choice to use java?Seems `jpcap` is the only way and your comment about `too much work` is a little discouraging

Comment: @Jim The packet hasn't been dropped only the information hasn't been forwarded. You would not be sending the original packet as you would have to change it in some way for it work.

Comment: @Jim like I said, it won't be easier in another language.  The problem is not the language but the fact you are working with RAW packets.

Comment: Proxy servers usually use plain TCP, not raw packets.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:What about a proxy that shapes or filters traffic?

Comment: @PeterLawrey:May be you can check out my related post if you can spare some minutes for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760623/what-are-the-various-types-of-proxy-servers-and-they-level-they-operate-on

Answer (score 0):

You won't see packetized segments if some other device breaks your large UDP packet into smaller packets.

When reading TCP you'll read bytes as a stream.  You'll have no idea how these bytes were actually sent.  You could read back 100 bytes, and they could have been sent over 10 packets for all you know.

There's no way to access this information in java without JNI. Of course with JNI you can do anything :)

Comment: How is this related to my question?

Comment: You asked if java could read application level packets.  The answer is yes.  It can. Let me elaborate. Maybe I misunderstood. I've edited to explain you cannot access TCP packets on a low level, or UDP packets on a low level. You just get the reassembled packet in UDP, and a stream for TCP.

Comment: Java provides UDP packet access, but I do not believe it provides TCP packet access. I suppose you could implement TCP with UDP if you were so inclined.

Comment: TCP is not built on UDP. TCP is built on IP... @corsiKa

Comment: @WilliamMorrison:I asked whether java can **ONLY** work on application level packets.Not if `Application level messages operate in TCP/UDP layer yes? If so you can certainly do this in java`

Comment: My apologies @Jim I've edited my answer so I think it now answers your question. If not, either you've mispoke, or I've misunderstood, and I will delete the answer. But yes, java only operates on a high level networking wise.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison:Not a problem!But from my point of view an answer mentioning `JNI` means that `Java` does not support it (since you have to actually code in another language for what you need)

Comment: Quite true.  So no, Java doesn't support it.

Comment: @WIlliamMorrison:+1 for the input

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that UDP == raw. It doesn't. Raw == IP, or even Ethernet. UDP is a layer over IP, as is TCP. You can't work in raw sockets in Java but you can work in UDP and TCP.

Comment: Can I work on the level of network packets though in `Java`? Could I build a proxy that shapes/filters traffic in `Java`?

Comment: @Jim No you can't, because you can't filter or suppress packets either in pure Java or Java + JPcap. I'm not aware of any Java JNI-based libraries that let you do that.

Comment: I was originally thinking a proxy that accepts a client request and reads packets but for example does *not* forward some to the actual destination. Isn't this filtering via Java? Or am I confused?

Comment: Certainly you can write a proxy that does anything you like, but that's a completely different thing from the question you asked. A proxy speaks a specific application protocol and is known to at least the client. 'Low level network programming' implies IP level, packet level, transparency to peers, etc.

Comment: The client does not need to be aware the level that the proxy operates on right? I mean if the proxy operates on `IP` level the client doesn't/shouldn't be affected and can still be an `http` client, right?