# How can I implement a proxy that handles both TCP and UDP in java?

Tags: java, tcp, proxy, network-programming, udp

I was looking into proxy implementations (I am interested in using `Java` as programming language).
I was wondering, is a proxy supposed to work on all protocols? E.g. `TCP` and `UDP`
A single protocol, e.g. `TCP` only?
Are proxies usually application level e.g. `HTTP`?
Is it possible to implement a proxy that can proxy TCP and UDP connections?
If I need to build a proxy that reshapes traffic e.g. blocks/drops packets or making some 
connections slower than others should I be working on `IP` level? Higher levels?

Comment: Why close?At least put a comment so that I can improve the question or move elsewhere or know what am I doing wrong

Comment: Normally people have a specific requirement they need to implement and they ask them how to do it.  Otherwise they can end up investigating all the thing you could possibly do and in general you can do anything you want, whether it is a good idea or not.  You have hinted at an actual requirement, perhaps you can explain what you are trying to do and you might find there are solutions which do this already.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:I am interested in writing something like a proxy in `Java` that can shape traffic. I.e. can make certain connection slower than others or even drop packets from specific connections

Comment: You can do that with a plain TCP proxy.  Instead of dropping packets you have a slow/delayed connection. From the receivers point of view it looks the same.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:Yes, I assume by doing a `sleep(2)` for example.But what if I want to simulate dropped packets?

Comment: You can simulate dropped packets by delaying the stream.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:For `TCP` that would be the same I agree.But for `UDP` not, since packets are dropped and is unreliable.So what would I do for `UDP`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey:Ok, but how am I supposed handle both `TCP` and `UDP`? By working on `IP` level? Or am I too complicating things?

Comment: They use different classes.  You have one program which supports both.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:You mean use a single server socket for both?And how would I know if it is a `TCP` connection or `UDP` connection?

Comment: @PeterLawrey:Last but most important!How do I know the `IP` this request should be forwarded to?

Comment: You need to configure the proxy to know what it should listen to and what to forward to, as well as the rate of delays and drops.

Comment: `You have one program which supports both` You mean in different ports right?

Comment: If you like. They can use the same port. The different protocols don't get confused.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:But how can they use same ports? To port `X` I can bind either a `ServerSocket` or a `DatagramSocket` right? And these classes are unrelated (both `extend` Object). So how could I use the same port from both classes?

Comment: You give them the same port number, and they will use the same port.

Answer (score 2):

> a proxy supposed to work on all protocols? E.g. TCP and UDP. A single protocol, e.g. TCP only?

It depends on whether it's a TCP proxy, a UDP proxy, both, or an application proxy.

> Are proxies usually application level e.g. HTTP?

Yes, and application proxies always are.

If I need to build a proxy that reshapes traffic e.g. blocks/drops packets or making some connections slower than others should I be working on IP level? Higher levels?

IP level. I wouldn't even call it a proxy, more of a filter.

Comment: 1) So I can simulate dropped packets via such an IP proxy? 2) For working on `IP` level my only option in `Java` would be `jpcap`? 3) I prefer `java` but is there another language better suited for this?